# SQL Merge Replication ignores filter

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have a merge replication (SQL 2005) with a filter.

The filter is on table delLog and says WHERE 0 = 1, so all the data is only uploaded, not downloaded.

When I want to download my data, and it comes to this table it says downloading table delLog and hangs there for an hour...

I get no errors for this it just hangs there...

any ideas how to solve this problem?